# How to forbid using a single Java class

Tags: java, swing, design-patterns, dependencies, dependency-management

I am currently using the factory pattern, which would call the JXErrorPane class. I want to make sure that no other class can call JXErrorPane directly. I tried the JDepend library, but it didn't work as I hoped as it only works for packages but there are other classes in the package which I don't want to move.

Is there a way to forbid other classes call JXErrorPane class except the factory class? Can this be done by configuring in IDE such as Eclipse or an explicit test is needed?

Thanks.

(The codebase is very huge as I'm enhancing other people's works. JXErrorPane is a swing class, it's called by just writing JXErrorPane.showDialog(). How can I make sure that only one class - the factory uses JXErrorPane, and all the other classes are forbids to use JXErrorPane)

Comment: where is your code ?

Comment: Start by using a `private` constructor, another idea is to expose only the `interface` of the API

Answer (score 0):

I guess by "call" you mean "create", ie. invoke the constructor.

No, you only have the 4 java access types public, protected, private and "default" which does not have a keyword.

An emerging pattern today is to include the factory in the class itself as a static method and keep construction private:

```
public class MyClass {
    private MyClass() { /* private constructor */ }

    // factory method
    public static MyClass create() {
        return new MyClass();
    }
}
```

Comment: JXErrorPane is a swing class, is there a way to limit only one class using it?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to solve this problem from this website: http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t53736.html

the JXErrorPane was in the ivy build path, so I configured the ivy build path it now rejects the use JXErrorPane now.

However I'm still not sure how to let the factory class to access JXErrorPane.

Comment: Fellow reviewers: this _is_ an answer. It does not depend on the link. It is not a complete answer, but it may still be useful for future visitors.